# Invoking method

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Hello fellow developers.

I am suppose to write a code that stores patient details and calculates some details like ratio. HDL(High Density Lipoprotein) and LDL are cholesterol figures. Please correct where ever you can.

I have a default constructor that assigns default values. And an overload constructor that has three parameters.

```
public PatientCheckUp()
{  
    PatientNumber = "L123";
    HDL = 60.00;
    LDL = 300;
}

public PatientCheckUp(String PatientNumber, double HDL,double LDL)
{
 this.PatientNumber = PatientNumber;
 this.HDL = HDL;
 this.LDL = LDL;
}
```

`

I already included the get and set methods, I understand those.
What i don't know how to do is

1. Create a method called getCholesterolStatus() that will invoke a method i created to compute cholesterol ratio ( computeRatio() )

This method must compare the patient's cholesterol ratio to that of the optimum cholesterol ratio and return a messaged based on the comparison. If the ratio is less than the ideal cholesterol the a "optimal cholesterol ratio" message should be returned(3.33)

The computeRatio() method

```
public double computeRatio()
{
  ratio = LDL / HDL;
  return ratio;
}
```

I realize i have asked for a lot. I need to understand how to do this for my upcoming examination.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the code for computeRatio(). It will help us in understanding what exactly it is doing and even you can give a brief summary about it.

Comment: Do you have already implemented the `computeRatio()` method? Provide it! I'm the only one who doesn't really understand the problem? The method `computeRatio()` already return a status about the cholesterol level or? What should `getCholesterolStatus()`  do? Return the difference between status and optimal ration as string? Return the current level of cholesterol?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @Josh.Carter Okay thanks! But I still don't understand what `getCholesterolStatus()` should do?!

Comment: This will be a tough exam if this is tripping you up. You might want to spend some time actually studying Java.

Comment: @0x1C1B I forgot the IDEAL_CHOLESTEROL final double variable that holds the value considered to be the best ratio for cholesterol, which is 3.33. Here's the full question, maybe you'll understand this better......    "Include a method called getCholesterolStatus(), that will invoke the computedRatio() method. The method must compare the patient's cholesterol ratio to that of the optimum cholesterol ratio and return a suitable message based on the comparison. If the ratio is less or equal to the IDEAL_CHOLESTEROL, then the application should display the message "Optimal cholesterol ratio" "

Comment: @0x1C1B If the ratio is greater, then the message should display "bad cholesterol ratio" and the message should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You call a method by typing its name and () at the end of it, possibly passing parameters and an instance variable's name before it with a dot or class name ahead of it with a dot if necessary. If you call a method correctly, then you can use it simply as a value, compare it to a final variable and you can also use the ternary operator to make this a one-liner.

```
public String getCholesterolStatus() {
    return (IDEAL_CHOLESTEROL <= computeRatio()) ? "Optimal cholesterol ratio" : "Bad cholesterol ratio";
}
```